# How to implement `cl-print-object`?

Tags: object, common-lisp, elisp, cl-lib

I am using `'eieio` and `'cl-lib` and I'm trying to define the `object-print` method for my class as described here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eieio.html#Basic-Methods

```
(cl-defmethod object-print ((this data-object) &optional strings)
  "Return a string with a summary of the data object as part of the name."
  (apply #'cl-call-next-method this
         (format " value: %s" (render this))
         strings))
```

I want to do this so I can see the contents of my object instances when I'm using edebug.

When I implement this example in my own code it produces the error message `the function ‘render’ is not known to be defined`.

In addition to the error message, Flycheck suggests: `‘object-print’ is an obsolete generic function (as of 26.1); use ‘cl-print-object’ instead.` I cannot find any documentation on the `cl-print-object` function when I Google, and I am failing at guessing how to implement it:

```
(cl-defmethod cl-print-object ((this card) &optional strings)
  "Return a string with a summary of the data object as part of the name."
  (apply #'cl-call-next-method this
         (format " value: %s" (slot-value this 'value))
         strings))
```

I do not know what to provide instead of `(slot-value this 'value)`.  It does not seem to want a slot.

How can I implement the `cl-print-object` function?  Or is there a better way to see the contents of an EIEIO object instance when debugging inside edebug?

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-print.el

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand elisp's CLOSoid system, but something like this is at least a start:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((x :initform 1
      :inirarg :x
      :reader foo-x)))

(defmethod cl-print-object ((f foo) stream)
  (princ (format "#<%s x %s>"
                 (class-name (class-of f))
                 (foo-x f))
         stream))
```

Now:

```
ELISP> (make-instance 'foo :x 2)
#<foo x 2>
ELISP> (defclass bar (foo) ())
bar
ELISP> (make-instance 'bar :x 2)
#<bar x 2>
```

Obviously in real life you want to extract more information from the object: I don't know if there is an equivalent of CL's `print-unreadable-object` which provides a nice approach to this without requiring you do to all the work by hand.

Comment: The default printer uses `eieio-class-slots` I guess, for example `#s(test 3 eieio--unbound)`

Comment: This works, thanks.  I did switch to using `cl-defmethod`, `eieio-class-name`, and `eieio-object-class` as suggested by Flycheck deprecation warnings.